# Cauchy-Riemann Equations on disconnected open set

Tags: complex-analysis

The following theorem is basic and well known:

**Theorem** if $f=u+iv$ is defined on a domain $D$ (open and connected), then $f$ is analytic on $D$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ have continuous partial derivative on $D$ that satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Why $D$ have to be connected? Does this theorem is true also for a **disconnected open** set, say on $D=\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$? I did not find any counterexample.

Comment: Thanks @Fenris, but the the set is open so why the directions is important? We compute the derivative in a small circle. don't we?

Comment: the result is local, so it depends only on a small open neighborhood of the point, hence it holds on open but not connected sets (proof - pick a component, it is open and connected, hence the usual result applies)

Comment: Thanks @Conrad, but what if the open set $D$ is composed with two parts, such as $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$? Do you have an example for such function?

Comment: Yes, I withdrew my previous comment as I saw that in my own introductory text on complex analysis ("Fundamentals of complex analysis", Saff & Snider), connectedness is not required in the corresponding theorem.

Comment: Thanks @Fenris. This sounds reasonable, since if $A,B$ are open sets and if $f$ is analytic on both $A$ and $B$, then it clearly analytic of $A\cup B$, not mater if $A\cup B$ is connected.

Comment: Not sure I get the comment - the only thing is that the functions on various components may be totally unrelated -  pick your favorite analytic function on the upper plane which cannot be continued anywhere below the real line and a different (not the conjugate) similar one on the lower plane and put them together, or pick $0$ on a component and $1$ on another etc

Comment: What do you mean by putting them together ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your example @Conrad. You claim that the function $f$ define by $f(z)=1$, when $Re(z)>0$ and $f(z)=0$, when $Re(z)<0$ is not analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: It is analytic - but the functions are not "related" to one another; not sure what counterexample you want - the result as stated is true, namely on an open set connected or not, functions are analytic iff they are $C^1$ and satisfy C-R; the main issue with open but not connected sets is that the ring of analytic functions is not integral, so, for example, one can have zeroes accumulating at a point but the function not identically zero (see example above which has uncountably many zeroes but is not identically zero)

Comment: Thanks @Conrad for you answer.

Comment: happy to be of help , no problem